SonarQube can't find my JUnit test report files
in my sonar-project.properties file I have set the XML file destination as follows:
sonar.junit.reportPaths=./testreports/*.xml
however, in my Jenkins build logs for the project I see:
INFO: parsing [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cw-1/testreports/*.xml]
ERROR: Reports path not found or is not a directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cw-1/testreports/*.xml

The path does exists as I have verified via ssh into the EC2 instance:
see here
is there something I'm missing here?
I have tried to change the path using ** at the start of it.
I also tried copying the XML file directly to the project root but still nothing.

Please take a look at the description of the sonar.junit.reportPaths property: Comma-delimited list of paths to Surefire XML-format reports. If you use Google search, you will see that the path to folders is specified. Like this example here.

@Bademeister, I have also tried like this specifying the direct oaths to the xml files with commas. Same results unfortunately.

The error message is: Reports path not found or is not a directory. You have specified a path with a wildcard to files. Where are the files located when you run the tests locally?

@Bademeister, ~/cw-1/testreports and i assume when ran in jenkins it just copys that workpace to /var/lib/jenkins/workspaces/cw-1. I also have just specified the path testreports aswell.

Does it work now?
